# SELECT FROM one table and INSERT INTO another; using WHERE & AND

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO tblPubInfo i (img_name)
SELECT f.img_name
FROM tblPubFiles f 
WHERE f.img_name<>''
AND f.pub_uid = i.uid
```

this is what I am trying to do but it is giving me a error. What is wrong with it and how to fix it?

Comment: What's the error?  Based on the code, it's not obvious what the issue is.

Comment: That depends on the structures of `tblPubInfo` and `tblPubFiles` - if you give them, we might be able to help you.

Comment: And What is that error, can you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to update a recored with an insert into statement. That doesn't work. Use the following:

```
UPDATE tblPubInfo i
SET i.img_name = ( SELECT f.img_name 
                   FROM   tblPubFiles f 
                   WHERE  f.img_name is not null 
                   AND    f.pub_uid = i.uid
                 )
```

Answer (score 4):

Your are referencing the target table in Your condition (i.uid).
This is not allowed, because it does not appear in the tables (from clause).

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit hard to help you without supplying the error.

However, if your database is MySQL,

## MySQL doesn't support ALIAS on INSERTS

> INSERT INTO tblPubInfo i (img_name)

should be:

> INSERT INTO tblPubInfo (img_name)

see here:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be:

```
INSERT INTO tblPubInfo (img_name)
SELECT f.img_name
FROM tblPubFiles f, tblPubInfo i
WHERE f.img_name<>''
AND f.pub_uid = i.uid
```

Comment: That depends on the purpose of the statement, which is not clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables in the `Select` clause, in order to use the alias `i` for the table `tblPubInfo` like:

```
INSERT INTO tblPubInfo (img_name) 
SELECT f.img_name
FROM tblPubFiles f 
inner join tblPubInfo i on f.pub_uid = i.uid
WHERE f.img_name <> ''
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO tblPubInfo (img_name) 
SELECT a.img_name
FROM   tblPubFiles a INNER JOIN tblPubInfo b ON a.pub_uid = b.uid
WHERE  CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(a.img_name)) > 0
```